# Получить доступ из декоратора к полям класса

Tags: python, asyncio, декоратор

Имеется асинхронный декоратор определенный в классе. Как получить доступ к полям класса из декоратора?

```
class Hello(object):
template = 'Hello, {}'

    def hello(fun):
        @wraps(fun)
        async def wrapper(text):
            return await fun(self.template.format(text))
        return wrapper

    @hello
    async def b(self, text):
        print(text)
        return False


n = Hello()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(n.b('Maxim'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `wrapper` должна принимать ещё один параметр `self`. в `fun` надо передавать `self`

```
class Hello(object):
    template = 'Hello, {}'

    def hello(fun):
        @wraps(fun)
        async def wrapper(self, text):
            return await fun(self, self.template.format(text))
        return wrapper

    @hello
    async def b(self, text):
        print(text)
        return False


n = Hello()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(n.b('Maxim'))
```